# New line missing between 'notice' and 'related_site' member types

Tags: bug, documentation

At the bottom of http://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=type#docs under the *Member Types* section, `notice` and `related_site` are on the same line. A `<br>` is missing between the items.